# Using regex to extract link

Tags: java, html, regex, url

Hello I am trying since weeks to fetch programmatically an link in an web source code in Java however i have trouble using regex to do so here is what i tried so far:

```
private static StringBuilder a;
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{

    String a = "http://www.mediafire.com/download/w8kvregpyx3zncc/Candy+by+hack94.apk";

    URL yahoo = new URL(a);
    URLConnection yc = yahoo.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                               yc.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
    String inputLine;
    String regExp = "kNO = \"\"(.+?)\"\";";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile( regExp, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE );

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        // Using Oscar's RegEx.
        Matcher m = p.matcher( inputLine );  
        if( m.matches() ) {
            System.out.println( m.group(1) );
        }
    }
}

private static String getUrlSource(String url) throws IOException {
    URL yahoo = new URL(url);
    URLConnection yc = yahoo.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                               yc.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
    String inputLine;
     a = new StringBuilder();
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        a.append(inputLine);
    in.close();

    return a.toString();
}
```

The line which includes the random link i have to fetch

```
kNO = "RANDOM_URL";
```

Does anyone know what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you just share some samples: input and output expected using regular expression?

Comment: I dunno what you mean the code which i tryed i shared here already

Comment: Try using `m.find()` instead of `m.matches()`. And it looks like you have an extra double quote in the regex, use `String regExp = "kNO\\s*=\\s*\"(.+?)\"";`

Comment: still not outputting anything :(

Comment: unfortunely still nothing

Comment: but thx for trying to help

Comment: To match 'kNO = "RANDOM_URL";' USE:  "kNO\\s*=\\s*\".*?\";"